# SOAP service in spring boot

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, soap

I'm confused about the way I'm compelled to create a SOAP service in spring boot. I wrote many SOAP services in Java in the past, simply writing down the java code and not a line of XML. A very easy and error less approach.
All the tutorial I read for Spring Boot has the need to write an XSD document, form which maven will read and build the needed classes.

Is there a way, supported by Spring Boot, to bypass the XSD file and write directly the needed java classed instead?

Just to give you some example of what I read, here are some links to the tutorials I'm referring to:

- https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-soap-web-service-example
- https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-soap-webservice-example/
- https://www.javainuse.com/spring/springbootsoapwebservice

Comment: `Is there a way, supported by spring boot, to bypass the XSD file and write directly the needed java classed instead?` - What do you mean? XSDs are used to define the structure, which is mandatory when using soap. If you just want to use XML without schemas you can use REST instead.

Comment: I make you an example: if you use netbeans and you create a maven web project, you only need to right click on the project, select web service and then it build for you the skeleton of an empty SOAP service. From that you have only to add the methods, objects and so on that you need to fulfill the operations you need to implement. I tried this approach with spring boot, but it ignores my SOAP service.

Comment: Well, using XML and XSD is actually recommended, I believe people call it "contract first".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that writing the XML code to generate the Java one is very error prone and a really difficult to maintain code, when you're developing big services or services with a lot of objects. All works fine if you have a small project, that is not my case.

What I did was to write the classes and then generate the xsd file using *schemagen*.

This is the configuration in maven pom I added:

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>schemagen</id>
             <goals>
                 <goal>schemagen</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>

     <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsds/</outputDirectory>
            <transformSchemas>
                <transformSchema>
                    <uri>http://test/test-ws/MyTestSchema</uri>
                    <toPrefix>test</toPrefix>                            
                    <toFile>test.xsd</toFile>
                </transformSchema>
             </transformSchemas>
             <sources>
                 <source>${basedir}/src/main/java/my/classes/</source>
             </sources>
             <verbose>true</verbose>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```